# GetKeyDown not executing inside onTriggerStray2D, Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an object that teleports the player to a different scene when clicked.
I tried following this tutorial: `https://youtu.be/PpLJq6AR2J0`
This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Table : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject UiElement;

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            UiElement.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
               SceneManager.LoadScene("Table1");
            }
        }
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            UiElement.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried it executes everything except

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
               SceneManager.LoadScene("Table1");
            }
```

The code is correct and it executes when it's inside the update function. Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physics framerate update doesn't have to match the game framerate. The `Input.GetKeyDown` will be true only for one frame so it won't be called. You should put input checks like `Input.GetKeyDown` inside the `update` function.

This is not the best way to do it but only to show a way to do it:

```
 private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            UiElement.SetActive(true);
            colliderHit = true;   

        }
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
          if(colliderHit)
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Table1");
        }
          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, here is the solution:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Table : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool collided = false;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject UiElement;

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collided = true;
        }
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (collided == true)
        {
            UiElement.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && UiElement == true)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Table1");
            }
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collided = false;
            UiElement.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    
}
```

I just used a boolean called collided. That way u can check inside the `Update()` function.